# Can I use mysql to connect to SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am using mysql command line tool downloaded from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html - I have enabled remote connect to SQL Server but I can't connect to it using this. I am just wondering if it's because mysql client isn't compatible with SQL Server? If it's not, is there any client I can use on OS X or ubuntu?

Comment: A common purpose is to access mssql using mysql client without having to duel boot or have Microsoft Windows in a virtual environment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot use MySQL to connect to MSSQL.

You have to use clients that were specifically created to understand MSSQL protocol. One of the most popular solutions for this on Linux is [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/).

Also, you can use [ODBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server) or [JDBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server) drivers provided by Microsoft.

Comment: 2 links are broken now.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the SQuirreL SQL Client. It's written in Java, so it should run on both Linux and Mac, and it can connect to SQL server and basically any database server that has a JDBC driver.

http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/

You may need to download the JDBC driver separately from Microsoft.