# Connection to MSSQL from MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, linked-server

I have a MySQL DB on Ubuntu Server. Is any possibility to establish a connection with remote MSSQL DB and use this DB in query? For example, execute in MySQL query like this:

```
SELECT mysql_table.field1,
       mssql_table.field2
FROM   MySQL.table_name AS mysql_table,
       MSSQL.table_name AS mssql_table
WHERE  mysql_table.id = mssql_table.id
```

Comment: At this point of time we cannot do this

Comment: This is wrong direction of link. Your solution describe a link MySQL in MSSQL, but I want an access to MSSQL in MySQL. Moreover this link describe actions for Windows, but I have Unix system.

Comment: Not possible and I dont think it will be soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As from the explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186224/can-i-use-mysql-to-connect-to-sql-server) you cant use  `MySQL` to connect to `MSSQL`.

You will have to use any clients.You can use [FREETDS](http://freetds.schemamania.org/) client for linux.You can also use `OBDC` and `JDBC`.