# connecting MSSQL server using MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am trying to connect to database, which is on MSSQL server, using MySQL Workbench.

while creating new connection using workbench, I am getting error - "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 10060"

while looking for this error code - I got this link - [Can I use mysql to connect to SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186224/can-i-use-mysql-to-connect-to-sql-server)

any suggestions/link how I can connect to database on MSSQL server using MySQL workbench

Comment: The answer in the link you posted says that you can't connect to SQL Server. Why don't you want to use a tool such as [SQL Server Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062)?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Workbench is a tool exclusively designed to work with the MySQL server. No other RDBMs is supported.

To clarify after the migration comment:

Migration is something completely different. WB only migrates from certain RDBMSs, but always to MySQL. And all features in WB only work and were tested for a MySQL server.

Comment: i dont know if that's true anymore. in the migration assistant in mysql workbench, you can export a database to a saved mssql connection. its in the options, but apparently in order to use it, you need to set up the proper ODBC drivers to connect to it