# Database Integration with Mysql and SQL server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I would like to integrate table from two different databases (Mysql and SQL server).
What are different options available for this?

Comment: What do you mean my integration?

Comment: SQL server offers linked server capabilities so [mySQL accessible in SQL server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4577/create-a-linked-server-to-mysql-from-sql-server/).  Or  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186224/can-i-use-mysql-to-connect-to-sql-server

Comment: What is the problem or question? Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question."*

Answer (score 0):

you can export csv from MS SQL Server and imported back to MYSQL and vis versa

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Linked Servers are used to query remote databases for example, configure a linked server for a MySQL server from SQL Server.

Here you can find a tutorial explaining how you can configure your linked server and your Mysql to have them connected.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4577/create-a-linked-server-to-mysql-from-sql-server/