# Cannot manage docker-based mysql server from Linux

Tags: sql-server, docker

I installed an mssql server using docker container in an ubuntu EC2 as follows:

```
sudo docker run --name my_mssql -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=<mypassword>" -p 1433:1433 -v /home/ubuntu/db:/var/opt/mssql -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux
sudo netstat -lpnt |grep 1433
```

shows 1433 is listening

I can login the mssql server using username=sa and password=mypassword using SQLPRO for MSSQL – a database manager, I can then create a database from that manager.

However, if I operate the mssql server from the EC2 in which the mssql server is installed, using the below command,

```
mysql -h <EC2 IP> -P 1433 -u sa -p
```

and then provide the password, it just stuck there and finally stop connecting with error message:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 2
```

Why I cannot operate mssql server from the ubuntu EC2? How can I do that?

Comment: `MySQL` is one product, `SQL Server` is another. You can't use `mysql` to connect to SQL Server any more than you can use it to connect to Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL or SQLite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You DB server is `MSSQL`, and you are trying to connect with `MSSQL` using `Mysql` client, which will defiantly not work.

[Can I use mysql to connect to SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186224/can-i-use-mysql-to-connect-to-sql-server)

```
microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

you can verify accessibility using

```
telnet EC2_IP 1433
```

or you can use [sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/sqlcmd-start-the-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) or  [MSSQL client](https://www.sqlshack.com/working-sql-server-command-line-sqlcmd/) to connect with your DB container.

Comment: Thanks I now realized the command I use to connect mssql server is mysql, I thought it was mssql. these two words look so similar. Thanks I have install sqlcmd and use it to login the mssql server.

Answer (score 2):

You're using SQL Server, not MySQL. You can't use another database's tools to connect to it.

You need to use [SQL Server's command-line tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-ver15):

- *sqlcmd* is the CLI query tool, similar to `mysql`
- *bcp* is used for bulk import/export

You can also use [Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/?view=sql-server-ver15) (the unfortunate marketing name of what started as SQL Server Operations Studio). ADS can connect to SQL Server directly and  [PostgreSQL through an extension](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-data-studio-an-open-source-gui-editor-for-postgres/)

It's a cross-platform editor/IDE similar to Visual Studio Code built for querying, [visualizing results](https://www.sqlshack.com/create-charts-from-sql-server-data-using-azure-data-studio/), managing databases and executing [Python scripts and Jupiter Notebooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/notebooks-guidance?view=sql-server-ver15). It comes with [server and database dashboards](https://www.sqlshack.com/server-and-database-dashboards-in-azure-data-studio/) out of the box. There are several extensions for advanced monitoring and troubleshooting too.

It's also trivial to create new dashboards [based on your own queries](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/customizing-the-default-azure-data-studio-dashboards.html): Just copy the visualisations JSON definition into a settings file.

Comment: Thanks I now realized the command I use to connect mssql server is mysql, I thought it was mssql. these two words look so similar. Thanks I have install sqlcmd and use it to login the mssql server.